# PostgreSQL get first letter of each word (except...)

Tags: postgresql, regular-expression

I don't think I drank enough coffee today, but stuck on this for some reason.

Trying to get the first letter of each word, except a few stopwords.

Example "The United States of America" -> "USA"

```
select regexp_matches('The United States of America', '\y(?!(the|of)\y)\w', 'gi')
```

works fine, but it returns `setof text[]` .

How to convert that to a simple string? Or is there a better way than `regexp_matches`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options:

```
-- regexp_matches
SELECT string_agg(arr[1], '') AS string
FROM   regexp_matches('The United States of America', '\y(?!(the|of)\y)\w', 'gi') arr;

-- regexp_split_to_table
SELECT string_agg(left(word, 1), '')
FROM   regexp_split_to_table('The United States of America', '\s+') t(word)
WHERE  NOT (word ILIKE ANY ('{the,of}'::text[]));

-- Without regular expression
SELECT string_agg(left(word, 1), '')
FROM   unnest(string_to_array('The United States of America', ' ')) t(word)
WHERE  NOT (word ILIKE ANY ('{the,of}'::text[]));
```

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/88843/22)

Option 2 splits on **any amount of white space**. Not *exactly* the same as your regex.
Option 3 splits on a **single space character**. If you can rely on that (?), the query is cheaper.

Comment: Going to go with option 1, as it's the simplest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPLACE(array_to_string(array(select array_to_string(regexp_matches('The United States of America', '\y(?!(the|of)\y)\D', 'gi'),'')),''),' ','');
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3083)